# Date range betwen now and end of the day and next day and end of the next day

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a DatePicker with a choice between today and tomorrow. Two buttons to switch Date Range.

How to make today range? i. e. Now -> End of the day

How to make tomorrow range? i. e. Start of the next day -> End of the next day

what i've tried, but it's not correct

```
 var todayRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var endComponents = DateComponents()
    endComponents.day = 1

    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: Date.now)!
    return Date.now ... endDate
}

var tommorowRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var startComponents = DateComponents()
    startComponents.day = 2
    var endComponents = DateComponents()
    endComponents.day = 1

    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: startComponents, to: Date.now)!
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: startDate)!
    return startDate ... endDate
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? What solutions have you researched?

Comment: @loremipsum check it

Comment: You should edit your question to explain how your attempt fails to meet your requirements. If you do that I'll up-vote your question, since at that point it would be a complete, well-formed question.

Comment: "it's not correct" is not enough for your readers to understand how your code isn't meeting your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

I would suggest:

- Get the start of day for today
- Add 1 day
- Subtract 0.001 seconds.

That will give you the end of today.

Here is some sample code.

```
let today = Date.now
let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: today)
let oneDay = DateComponents(day: 1)
guard let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: oneDay, to: startOfToday) else { fatalError() }

let endOfToday = tomorrow.advanced(by: -0.001)
let endOfTodayString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: endOfToday, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium)
print("End of today = " + endOfTodayString)

guard let endOfTomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: oneDay, to: endOfToday) else { fatalError() }
let endOfTomorrowString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: endOfToday, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium)
print("End of tomorrow = " + endOfTomorrowString)
```

In my locale (US), on October 7th, that generates:

> End of today = Oct 7, 2022 at 11:59:59 PM
>
> End of tomorrow = Oct 7, 2022 at 11:59:59 PM

Comment: simple and very clear! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. On SO when somebody answers your question you should click the checkmark to accept their answer. That is a very strong norm on this site. Up-votes are optional, but you are expected to accept the first/best answer you receive.